# I’m having trouble retrieving the value of a jquery data-attribute. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

anyone have time to take a quick look at this: http://caseydavis.org/jquerytest/test.html -- There's a select box that has a value and a data-value. I echo them both in console.log, one is defined and one isn't. What am I doing wrong on the data-label value?

```
<div class="item" style="margin-bottom:15px">
    <label><span class="item_title">Extra TV Remotes</span><p>One TV Remote is included with each Set Top Box. Order more below for an additional $20 each.</p>
        <div class="styled-select">
            <select id="extra_remote" name="extra_remote">
                <option data-onetimeprice="0.00" data-label="" value="0_extra_remotes">0 Extra Remotes</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="20.00" data-label="1 Extra Remote" value="1_extra_remotes">1 Extra Remote (+$20)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="40.00" data-label="2 Extra Remotes" value="2_extra_remotes">2 Extra Remotes (+$40)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="60.00" data-label="3 Extra Remotes" value="3_extra_remotes">3 Extra Remotes (+$60)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="80.00" data-label="4 Extra Remotes" value="4_extra_remotes">4 Extra Remotes (+$80)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="100.00" data-label="5 Extra Remotes" value="5_extra_remotes">5 Extra Remotes (+$100)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="120.00" data-label="6 Extra Remotes" value="6_extra_remotes">6 Extra Remotes (+$120)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="140.00" data-label="7 Extra Remotes" value="7_extra_remotes">7 Extra Remotes (+$140)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="160.00" data-label="8 Extra Remotes" value="8_extra_remotes">8 Extra Remotes (+$160)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="180.00" data-label="9 Extra Remotes" value="9_extra_remotes">9 Extra Remotes (+$180)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="200.00" data-label="10 Extra Remotes" value="10_extra_remotes">10 Extra Remotes (+$200)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<script>
$("#extra_remote").change(
    function() {
        console.log( $(this).val() );
        console.log( $(this).data('label') );
        $('#onetime_value').text($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the identifier you choose for the select attribite data-label is wrong. Please use this console.log( $('#extra_remote option:selected').attr('data-label') ); instead. jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jgwtmzs1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `change` listener is added to the `#extra_remote` element, so `this` inside the callback refers to the `#extra_remote` element (which is a `<select>`, which doesn't have the `label` data attribute). If you want to access the selected `<option>` instead, then do:

```
$(this.children[this.selectedIndex]).data('label')
```

```js
$("#extra_remote").change(
  function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    const label = $(this.children[this.selectedIndex]).data('label');
    console.log(label);
    $('#onetime_value').text($(this).val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" style="margin-bottom:15px">
  <label><span class="item_title">Extra TV Remotes</span><p>One TV Remote is included with each Set Top Box. Order more below for an additional $20 each.</p>
        <div class="styled-select">
            <select id="extra_remote" name="extra_remote">
                <option data-onetimeprice="0.00" data-label="" value="0_extra_remotes">0 Extra Remotes</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="20.00" data-label="1 Extra Remote" value="1_extra_remotes">1 Extra Remote (+$20)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="40.00" data-label="2 Extra Remotes" value="2_extra_remotes">2 Extra Remotes (+$40)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="60.00" data-label="3 Extra Remotes" value="3_extra_remotes">3 Extra Remotes (+$60)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="80.00" data-label="4 Extra Remotes" value="4_extra_remotes">4 Extra Remotes (+$80)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="100.00" data-label="5 Extra Remotes" value="5_extra_remotes">5 Extra Remotes (+$100)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="120.00" data-label="6 Extra Remotes" value="6_extra_remotes">6 Extra Remotes (+$120)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="140.00" data-label="7 Extra Remotes" value="7_extra_remotes">7 Extra Remotes (+$140)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="160.00" data-label="8 Extra Remotes" value="8_extra_remotes">8 Extra Remotes (+$160)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="180.00" data-label="9 Extra Remotes" value="9_extra_remotes">9 Extra Remotes (+$180)</option>
                <option data-onetimeprice="200.00" data-label="10 Extra Remotes" value="10_extra_remotes">10 Extra Remotes (+$200)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```